# Stuck on the login screen in Xubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, login, xfce

I installed Xubuntu DE on my machine and when I rebooted, my ubuntu got stuck on the login screen. Even the command to bring up the terminal <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> is not working and every time I enter the password, it prompts me to enter it again, and this loop continues... 
I installed Xubuntu using the command `sudo apt install xfce4` 
Kindly help. 
BTW I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: I had the same problem, try reinstalling the OS

Comment: During the bootup, when the Ubuntu logo is shown, press `Esc`. You will get a black screen showing text. Watch for any warning or error messages.